# Rust project workspace improvement accessibility

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

## Problem

Is there a cleaner way to name imports from member projects then this:

#### (1) libs/src/messages/server_message.rs

```
...
let states = libs::messages::server_message::ServerMessage::Welcome(id);
...
```

e.g. this without changing the source code:

```
...
let states = libs::messages::ServerMessage::Welcome(id);
...
```

## Project setup

Following [workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html) approach.

My project looks like this

[image]

#### (2) Cargo.toml

```ini
...
[workspace]

members = [
    "libs",
]

[dependencies]
libs = { path = "libs" }
...
```

#### (3) libs/src/libs.rs

```
pub mod messages;
```

#### (4) libs/src/messages/mod.rs

```
pub mod client_message;
pub mod remote_state;
pub mod server_message;
pub mod state;
```

#### (5) libs/src/messages/server_message.rs

```
...
pub enum ServerMessage {
    Welcome(usize),
    Goodbye(usize),
    Update(Vec<RemoteState>),
}
...
```

Comment: Are you using `use` to import items? Generally you would import the thing you are using so you don't need to write the full path every time. For example, you could add `use libs::messages::ServerMessage;` at the top of the module then you would only need to do `let states = ServerMessage::Welcome(id);`.

Comment: You are ofc right. For simplicity (less code) I did not use **use**. My question is more about somekind of **re-export** to provide a cleaner **lib**. Thank you.
Update: your example should be `use libs::messages::server_message::ServerMessage;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only changes required

#### (4) libs/src/messages/mod.rs

```
...
mod server_message;
pub use crate::messages::server_message::ServerMessage;
...
```

I could then use following import

#### (1) libs/src/messages/server_message.rs

```
let states = libs::messages::ServerMessage::Welcome(id);
```